# What is the Correct plural for 'Dark elf'

Tags: elves, legend-of-drizzt

I recently read the *Legend of Drizzt* trilogy and am rather confused with the plural for 'Dark elf', as multiple times in the books they are referred to as Drow, Drow elves or Dark elves.

**Is There A Correct Plural For Dark Elf?**

(It's my first time using this website, please comment if there is any way to improve this question.)

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the Legend of Drizzt trilogy, or in general? The first would be on-topic here, the second wouldn't be, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Legend of Drizzt is set in the Forgotten Realms and is a D&D setting. The creatures in question are known as "drow" in both singular and plural. They are a type of elf that was typically restricted to NPC status, but which clearly isn't the case here. Thus they also borrow the elven naming convention of X elf/X elves (wood elf, sun elf, moon elf, etc.)

Comment: In other words, Drizzt can be called a Drow, a dark elf, or even a Drow elf. And therefore, The inhabitants of (say) Menzoberranzan can thus be Drow, dark elves, or Drow elves. All three are correct plurals.

Comment: @RDFozz Not quite correct, since "drow" is not a proper noun.

Comment: So, "drow" not "Drow", otherwise correct?